# Sql select with grouping rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008

In mssql-db I have a table with 5 columns.
id, 1st_t1, 1st_t2, 2nd_t1, 2nd_t2

it's single "task" with 2 parameters(t1,t2) "grouped" by  person type(1st,2nd)

Is it possible to select info like this on picture in Reporting Service?:

[image]

Or the only way is divide this table on two tables for each person type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your report, your detail must have two rows.

On the first you will drag and drop the data of the 1st person and on the second row for the second like in the image below

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer. You can do it directly in reporting services keeping your query intact

Comment: i'm very sorry. it was really simple obvious solution. many thanks

Comment: You are welcome! Maybe it's obvious sometimes, but the first solution came to my mind was making changes to SQL which was not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:

```
WITH T(ID, First_t1, First_t2, Second_t1, Second_t2)
AS
(
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 1 ID, '1st_t1' First_t1, '1st_t2' First_t2, '2nd_t1' Second_t1, '2nd_t2' Second_t2
UNION
SELECT 2 ID, '1st_t1' First_t1, '1st_t2' First_t2, '2nd_t1' Second_t1, '2nd_t2' Second_t2
UNION
SELECT 3 ID, '1st_t1' First_t1, '1st_t2' First_t2, '2nd_t1' Second_t1, '2nd_t2' Second_t2 
) A
)
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT '1st person' person, Id,First_t1 t1,First_t2 t2 FROM T
union
SELECT '2nd person' person, Id,Second_t1 t1,Second_t2 t2 FROM T
) B
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: This was my first thought, but it can be done directly in reporting services keeping SQL simple and faster.